# HTML email template in Outlook 2022

Tags: html, css, email, background-image, html-email

I'm implementing a fancy email template for my friend, and of course, I faced various issues when I started testing my HTML email template with Outlook. So far so good, I found how to implement background images using VML and went through different tutorials and courses.
Currently, I faced a very strange issue using a working template from one of the tutorials which I used to learn. Both I and my friend use the same Outlook Desktop version 2211 (Build 15831.20208)
The background images on my outlook are looking pretty good, like:

[my Outlook email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4tKm.png)

In his outlook, the background image is not resized well.
Has anyone have an idea what could be the reason could it be template (it is strange since both of use same outlook version) issue, or it is more likely some outlook issue (configuration):
Here it is:
[the other Outlook email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2oCv.jpg)

Here is how my code looks like:

```
<tr>
   <td background="https://i.ibb.co/hMhVbjT/stats2.gif" width="600" height="332" style="background-position: center top;">

      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:332px;">
         <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.ibb.co/hMhVbjT/stats2.gif" />
         <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
      <![endif]-->
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing trouble with the background image size you need it covers the whole screen and I think this code would help you with that:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/hMhVbjT/stats2.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution probably will work if the image should be a background for the entire body, but that's not the case.